# Asp dropdown list boolean value is always set to false?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is my view

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Product.InStock">Available:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="Product.InStock">
            <option value="False">No</option>
            <option value="True">Yes</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

And this is model Product.cs

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Available")]
    public bool InStock { get; set; }
```

The problem is that the value sent to Controller method is always false, even when I choose option "Yes".

Comment: You didn't set a "name" value for your control, so it will never be posted back. Probably you'd be best using an asp-for helper to set the values correctly, just like you do for your label.

Comment: How do you send it to the controller? Ajax? Form POST? I don't see a `name` attribute on that input so it won't post it.

Comment: you have an id, but not a name on the the select element.  the model binder works off of name attributes

Comment: @Fran Small point, but technically, the model binder works off the parameters which are submitted in the HTTP request. It's the mechanism the browser uses to decide which parameters to send when parsing a form which uses the name attribute. The contents of the parameters in the request can still be altered by script. Or, the request can be submitted by a non-browser client and then the concept of form elements with "name" attributes is entirely redundant, but if the correct data is in the HTTP request, the model binder will still bind it.

Comment: I am using form method="post", could any of you show me how to use this "name" attribute?

Comment: @ADyson Yes.  You are right.  The model binder does come in after the initial HTTP request and works off the name/value keys of the request.

Comment: @ChrisK. as a generic example `<select id="someID" name="someName">`. When the form posts back you'll get a parameter like `someName=theSelectedValue` in the resulting HTTP request. That's how all HTML forms work, regardless of what the backend server runs. But like I said ASP.NET will help you create the correct attributes if you use an `asp-for` tag with your model property, just like you did with your `label` control - then the server-side Razor engine will use that to render the correct HTML in the browser, in order to post the form back with the correct parameter name.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, the value is always null

Comment: "it" was what, exactly? What did you change your code to look like, precisely?

Comment: P.S. Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms#the-select-tag-helper ? `<select class="form-control" asp-for="Product.InStock">` would seem to be the very obvious thing to do.

Comment: but then, how can i set value as an object? because it accepts just a string

Comment: what value and what object are you talking about? I don't understand your problem. Can you clarify? Inside the `asp-for` you put the name of your model property. Just like the other `asp-for`s you've used just above and below! It's the same!! P.S. Did you _try_ this? Did it help? P.P.S. I checked back to this question by chance. If you want to alert me you need to tag my username in your comment prefixed with @. e.g. @ADyson -
 Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't set a "name" value for your control, so it will never be posted back.

In your situation, since you're using ASP.NET Core MVC, the best way to solve this would be to use an `asp-for` tag helper in your select, just like you do for the label and validation control which are associated with the same "Product.InStock" attribute of your model.

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="Product.InStock">
```

This way, ASP.NET will generate the correct id and name attributes on the control so it will bind to your model when the form posts back.

Of course, if your view's Model is directly `Product` (and not some ViewModel where `Product` is merely one property from it), then *all* your `asp-for` tags relating to `InStock` need to be simply `asp-for="InStock"` instead.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms#the-select-tag-helper for more details of the tag helper for `<select>` controls

P.S. If you're just binding to a simple True/False bool as per your example code, a Checkbox might be the more appropriate type of form control from a usability perspective. Then the user only has to click once to set the value, instead of twice.

If you want to bind to another type, e.g. int or string, so that you can have lots of potential values for the field, and you want to dynamically populate the list of options (e.g. from database data) you can use the `asp-items` helper tag to tell ASP.NET to load the list from a server variable - details and an example are shown in the documentation in the link above.

Comment: product is needed for your varible name!

Comment: my answer is correct please test it before vote negative to it.

Comment: @AliRasouli "product is needed for your varible name!" would you care to explain how? As I explained, it _might_ be, depending on exactly what the model definition is. OP didn't specify that. However in _your_ example, it **definitely** isn't correct because you've specified a model for the postback which does not include Product _anywhere_.

Comment: please test bottom answer and debuge and trace it.

Comment: @ADyson yes I have changed the dropdown list to checkbox and now it works fine

Answer (score -1):

please consider bottom three note:

1. for false option do not need to value for option.
2. do not need to require property in code.
3. please name attribute in select tag(do not need to id)

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="InStock">Available:</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="Product.InStock" id="InStock">
         <option @(ViewBag.Product!=null || ViewBag.Product.InStock==false? "selected":"")>No</option>
         <option @(ViewBag.Product!=null && ViewBag.Product.InStock? "selected":"") value="true">Yes</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public class testClass
{ 
    public bool InStock { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult UserPermission(testClass Product)
{
    ViewBag.Product=Product;
    //Product.InStock filled true if yes option is selected
    return View()
}
```

Comment: What's the point of setting `[Display(Name = "Available")]` if you aren't going to make use of it in the view? The whole point of the tag helpers, which you've removed for some reason, is to neatly bind the model to the view including all the metadata, without having to endlessly repeat the same text, values, attributes etc, and to ensure that changes to the model do not silently break the view.

Comment: Also if the model is `testClass` and "InStock" is a property of the model, then it would need to be `name="InStock"` - see my answer. There's no such thing as the "Product" attribute in your example model.

Comment: Product is varible name that contain another varible that name is InStock.

Comment: "Product is varible name that contain another varible that name is InStock." ...but in your example right above, `public class testClass
{ 
    [Display(Name = "Available")]
    public bool InStock { get; set; }
}` shows that statement to be incorrect. Tell me, where is "Product" in there? Just because you called your input variable Product is not relevant, the model binder doesn't use that. It binds the names directly to the attributes of the model, with no sub-levels.

Comment: i removed  [Display(Name = "Available")] attrib from my code.

Comment: Ok, so you are partially right: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9qt38h - it works without "Product". And https://dotnetfiddle.net/mGiJkY - it works _within_ "Product" (they are using .NET 4.5 not Core, but the principle is the same). But...using "Product" is more brittle since it requires the variable in the action method to be always called "Product". Also, your way does not re-bind the value in the dropdown to the model after a postback, which is not very good. See both demos for an example of that. Whereas if tag helpers are used, then the binding is done by ASP.NET automatically.

Comment: and change my cshtml page.

Comment: You've somewhat missed my point. This code would work but in asp.net core, as I mentioned in my answer, you can use the much nicer asp-items helper tag to fetch the options, and the asp-for will bind and set the currently selected item. And in traditional ASP.NET you'd use an EditorFor helper. This way is just producing unnecessarily verbose code soup when a ready-made solution exists already. I don't know why anyone would want to do that? Do you use HTML helpers yourself when you write your MVC code, or not? If not, you really should consider it, it will save lots of time.

Comment: but my code is simple html and write good and feel all line of code.

Comment: It might produce simple HTML but it's not simple Razor. It produces the same HTML as you could produce with `<select class="form-control" asp-for="Product.InStock" asp-items="Products">`. Why bother?

Comment: simplify is power!! please vote true to my code. my code is true.

Comment: It works but it's not very maintainable or readable, and it doesn't follow best practice for MVC applications. If you were in my team and I was reviewing it I'd ask you to change it for something sustainable and easier to understand. The line I gave above is simpler, easier to read, less code and uses the built-in tools in the framework to make the coding easier, less error-prone and less vulnerable to changes. "Working" is not the only measure of good quality code.